# compute definite integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

i have the data below

[image: Three Columns[X,Y,Z]

the columns are X,Y and Z

i want to compute this Integral

[image]

i don't know how to do it in matlab

i searched and didn't find any case like my problem with the integration limits are array values,the variables are also arrays.
and i really don't know how to solve it mathematically 
i tried solving ,but the Y,Z and X being arrays with double values is not making things easy

Comment: You can use any numerical method (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/lab/people/sd/lectures/nummeth98/integration.htm). Basically you compute the value of Y(Z - 25) and multiply it by the step dx (which you can compute from your excel file) and you sum all those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following if you store X, Y and Z in MATLAB:

```
fyz = Y*(Z - 25);

% Compute the integral
I = trapz(fyz, X);
```